# How to add custom styling to Angular material forms

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

What is the proper way to theme an angular material form, local to a component?

I have a few form elements in my component template like this:

```
<mat-form-field class="signin-input">
    <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="email" formControlName="email">
</mat-form-field>
```

I want the placeholder text and the label to be #FFF, it's #000 initially.
I am adding these styles to the component scss, **but they are not taking effect**:

```
.mat-form-field-label,
.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
    color: #FFF !important;
}
```

I see that the styles in **theming.scss** is always being applied, irrespective of my stylesheet:

```
@mixin mat-form-field-theme($theme) {
    ....
    ....
    .mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
        color: #000;

        &.mat-accent {
            color: #000;
        }

        &.mat-warn {
            color: #000;
        }
    }
```

I want the color to be **#FFF**, but they are always **#000**. I found [this link](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming), but its too much of a hassle for a simple change like this.

How do I go about this?

**PART - B**

I see that the styles that I write, are appended with **[_ngcontent-c16]**. I have found that removing this tag on the fly from the dev console makes my styles take effect. What is this [_ngcontent-c16] ?

The project was set-up from angular-cli, and I am new to SCSS and Angular5 (I have worked extensively on Angular 1)

Comment: You've tagged this both angular1 and angular5. Which one are you using? And are you using angular-material or angular-material2? Or some other library?

Comment: I have fixed the tags, Angular 5 + angular-material

Comment: There is a huge difference in the time you invested writing your question and the time you invested researching it. Use [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle). (i.e.: `<some-element [ngStyle]="{'color': '#fff'}">...</some-element>`

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu My question is in knowing the right way of doing it, to preferably write styles only in the css/scss file. I know I could get away with ngStyle or inline style, they work. Thats not what I'm looking for.

Comment: The *"right way of doing it"* largely depends on requirements. Most people want it to get the job done. Some want their code to be maintainable and easily changeable. You called this "a small change", so I assumed it's localized. One instance. As in, an exception. The right way to do it is to define a stylesheet of your own and override what you want to override. SCSS is still producing CSS. Same principles apply, it's just you have extra options for writing faster and cleaner.

Comment: I'm looking for the right method of overriding styles. I have actually defined a separate stylesheet, but they are not overriding the ones in theming.scss. Thats where I am stuck.

Comment: Angular Material2 has a good [theming guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming). Be sure to read that as well as the linked 'theming your components' guide.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Writing simple CSS styles wont override it, we need to use a special selector called `host`. [More about it here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host).

Here is what worked for me:

```
:host {
    .mat-form-field-label,
    .mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
        color: #FFF !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do leave a comment on why the down vote. Still open to knowing the right approach.